# Visual Studio - Build for multiple platforms based on configuration chosen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, .net-5

I'm developing a C# cross-platform @ .NET5 application.

To build the project for linux I'm using `<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` in the .csproj file for each of the solution's projects but sometimes I also want to build the project for `win-x64`.

Is it possible to edit the .csproj file so the `RID` will be chosen according to a build configuration? i.e similar to the `Debug` or `Release` configurations, I want to have `Linux` and `Windows` configuration in Visual Studio.

I've managed to do the following which seems to work except it won't break on breakpoints on `Debug-Linux-x64` with WSL2 debugging.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Release-Linux-x64' ">
        <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug-Linux-x64' ">
        <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Release-Windows-x64' ">
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug-Windows-x64' ">
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify the DebugType to "portable", which is specifically for cross platform.

The related link:

- [Portable PDBs](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Portable-PDBs)